# google cloud function "functions.storage.object()" is returning 'Object: undefined'

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I used to have a simple function that pings my slack anytime a new document is uploaded to a firebase storage. After the node version it was on was deprecated I updates to a newer version (14). This was the code

```
exports.newUpload = functions
.storage
.object()
.onFinalize(async (object) => {
  try {
    console.log("Object:", object);
    const filePath = object.name;
    console.log(`Sending ${filePath}`);
    await request.post(webhook, { json: { text: `new file!: ${filePath}` } });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Now the function keeps throwing up an error:

```
textPayload: "Object: undefined"
```

I am really stumped. Everything else is the same in the code.

Comment: `onFinalize()` accepts [`google.storage.object.finalize`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents/blob/main/proto/google/events/cloud/storage/v1/data.proto) as an argument which does not respond to `toString()`. Try [accessing the properties of the object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#access-storage-object-attributes) to see if any of those respond to `console.log()`.